# text-align center not centering text in button

Tags: jquery, css

I have a square button with the attribute `'text-align':'center'`. It looks like there is extra padding on the left of the text within though:

[image]

I think it might have to do with the unicode character I'm using (9881) but I'm not sure. The css for the button looks like this:

```
$(prefButton).text(String.fromCharCode(9881)).css({
    'position':'absolute',
    'border':'1px solid black',
    'width':'40px',
    'height':'40px',
    'background-color':'transparent',
    'bottom':'3px',
    'left':'40px',
    'font-size':'150%',
    'text-align':'center'
})
```

Does anybody have a solution to center the character right in the middle of the button? I'm making it spin when hovered on so if it's not right in the center it's rotation looks wobbly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is probably related to the font size of the container element your button is in. The `font-size` of 150% is relative to *something*, while the width and height are fixed in pixels. That could give you unexpected results.

Cf. example of where it could go wrong in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xukmLzvz/